# Empty MetaModel when using EclipseLink 2.7.4

Tags: eclipselink

My application has a composite persistence unit **mainPU** which contains 2 members (**queryPU** and **entityPU**). When using Criteria API in EclipseLink 2.5, it did not have any problem. However, when upgrading to EclipseLink 2.7, it got error "No [EntityType] was found for the key class [**XXX**] in the Metamodel" where **XXX** is the class defined in **entityPU**

I have some observation regarding the issue:

1. This problem only occurred when using Criteria API, and there is no
   problem when using JPQL.
2. By default, my application load the **mainPU**. If I try to get the meta model, it always return empty list. If I explicitly load the
   EntityManagerFactory with **entityPU** in a DAO, then it can load the full list of EntityType, and the problem gone!

   ```
   EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("entityPU");

   Metamodel m2 = factory.getMetamodel(); //m2 return a list of EntityType!
   ```

Is there any wrong configuration in my application for the EclipseLink 2.7?

Below show the persistence.xml

**mainPU**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">


<persistence-unit name="mainPU" transaction-type="JTA">

    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/appds</jta-data-source>  
    <jar-file>icms-entity-lib-0.2.9.544.jar</jar-file>
    <jar-file>../icmshrnmc-ejb.jar</jar-file>

    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/persistence/mainPU" />
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database"
            value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform" />
        <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss" />
        <property name="eclipselink.composite-unit" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer"
            value="x.y.ejb.dao.entity.DefaultEntityInterceptor" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" />
        <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true"/>
    </properties>  

</persistence-unit>
```

**queryPU**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">


<persistence-unit name="queryPU" transaction-type="JTA">

    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/appds</jta-data-source>

    <mapping-file>x/y/icmshrnmc/model/common/dao/namedquery/HrnNat.orm.xml</mapping-file>
    ... 
    ... 
    ... 


    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.composite-unit-member" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**entityPU**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="entityPU" transaction-type="JTA">

<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/appds</jta-data-source>
<non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/appds</non-jta-data-source>


<mapping-file>x/y/fmk/model/application/dao/entity/AuditEntity.orm.xml</mapping-file>
... 
... 
... 


<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
<properties>

    <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.sequence-connection-pool" value="true" />
    <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.sequence-connection-pool.non-jta-data-source" value="java:jboss/datasources/fmkseqds" /> 
</properties>
```

Comment: Does anything else about that persistence unit work, or is it just that the factory.getMetamodel is empty?

Comment: Seems just the factory.getMetamodel is empty. So that's why those JPQL work fine in my application, while it throw exception for Criteria API.

Comment: Is it the bug in EclipseLink2.7.4? Our application have to upgrade EclipseLink as there is bug for batch fetch in EclipseLink2.5 which solved in 2.7.

Comment: I don't know, but I suspect it is a class loader issue. Turning on logging to finest and running first against 2.5 to get a baseline, then later with 2.7 might show something in how/when the mainPU is loaded that points to why it can't get at the meta model, or even when it is trying to loading that persistence unit to build the meta model.  You might also try setting eclipselink.deploy-on-startup to false, a difference in the settings you've shown, as maybe this PU is deployed too early at at time it cannot scan the specified jar-files.